# Which server push technology can I use in my HTML web application?

Tags: websocket, push, long-polling, server-push, server-sent-events

I am searching for a server push technology for my web application.
I would like to use a similar technology as StackOverflow, as that one is working very well.
So, are there any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know exactly what they use on the server side but you can see they are using WebSockets and some ajax (they look like polls) requests if you open your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Can it be other proposals for push technology as well, or must it be the one of StackOverflow

Comment: @KornP yes it can be otheres as well.

Answer (score 1):

For server-to-client push [Server-Sent Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) is a better choice than WebSockets. GitHub uses SSE for automatically showing new comments, pull requests, etc.

- SSE is HTTP-compatible, so it will work with proxy servers and you won't need HTTPS to have it working in practice (e.g. plenty of mobile operators have a HTTP proxy that breaks unencrypted WebSockets, but SSE works fine).
- SSE connection is lightweight and quick. There's no extra handshake and connection upgrade procedure. If you have SSE on every page, then your server will have less work to do.
- SSE protocol is super simple. You don't need special web server or library for it, and it can be [polyfilled](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) for old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [QWebSockets](http://kurtpattyn.github.io/QWebSockets/), if you control the server-side.
Otherwise, socket.io is a good candidate.
There are also ghosted services like Pusher and PubNub, which are free for a moderate number of push messages.

Comment: is there a fallback for older browsers with QWebSockets?

Comment: The fallback I use is ChromeFrame for IE9 and below. Beyond that, no fallbacks are foreseen in the server code.